# git double checkout, folder content gone

Tags: git, gitignore, git-checkout

I have a git repository with a master and developer branch.
Say my branch is called `branch1`.
Inside my repo I have a folder called `myfolder`. I was on `branch1` and I did

```
git checkout master
git checkout branch1
```

`myfolder` is now empty (sic), how did this happen?

I should note that `myfolder` is included in the `.gitignore` which I suspect is the cause of the problem, but I don't understand why. Also is there a way to restore its content?

Comment: Not cleared what you did, you had a folder with content and when switching branches the content gone?

Comment: Yes exactly, so say at time 0 I'm on branch1. I checkout first to master and then to branch1 so I should return where I was. However in the process the content of the folder is erased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your explanation of the situation and your observations, I deduce the following:

1. On the `master` branch, the folder `myfolder` is part of the repository.
2. On the `branch1` branch, the folder is not part of the repository, and it is being excluded from Git using a `.gitignore` rule.

So you start on `branch1`, the folder exists but is ignored by Git, so Git does not know about its contents. Now, you switch to the `master` branch; that branch does track the contents of that folder. When switching to it, Git compares the contents of the (untracked) local files with the ones from the `master` branch. Because it does not run into any differences, there is no conflict when checking out the branch, so it works fine.

You end up with the `master` branch, and the *tracked* `myfolder` folder. Now, you switch back to `branch1`: The `myfolder` folder is part of the `master` branch you are switching away from, but it does not exist on the `branch1` branch. So Git will remove it. That’s how you end up on `branch1` without that folder.

Unfortunately, Git does appear to overwrite the contents without doing the check it usually does when it detects the possibility of losing uncommitted content. This is likely due to the ignore rule. So I’m afraid, it won’t be possible to restore the exact contents from your uncommitted state before. You only have whatever is on `master`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it definitely makes sense. I will now go to cry against git for the nth time.